# Multiple accounts to user in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

In my meteor-angular application, i have 2 accounts-login configured:
Facebook and Google

Now, lets say that user A logged in with his Facebook account.
After the login, i'm sending the user to an additional form page to insert his social id(this form page is been shown to the user only once).

So now i have a user object(`Meteor.user()` + his social id).

The user is working in the application and insert his assets.

Now the the user decides to logout.

After a while he goes back to the application and this time he logs in with his Google account. So now he will be redirected to the "Insert Social ID" page form again since a new user was created in the DB.

Is there a way to bind those 2 users? I have a unique identifier(social id) which could help me merge them but do not find a way to do that binding...

I need that binding because if he is logged with different id, he won't be able to edit his assets...

10x

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`onCreateUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) callback. Find an already registered user with that social ID, and if it exist, then just add the new service object to the existing user document.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  // Find an existing user based on social ID
  let registeredUser = Meteor.users.findOne(...); 

  if(registeredUser) {
    let googleProfile = user.services.google;

    if (googleProfile) {
      // Add Google login credentials to the user document in Mongo
      Meteor.users.update({...}, {$set: {"services.google": googleProfile});
    }

    // throw an Error here to stop creating a new user.
  }

  // Returning a user object will create a new one in Mongo.
  return user;
});
```

Disclaimer: I would generally advise **against** merging users. Please consider that a malicious attacker who stole your Facebook password could steal your data in this service too, even if you only registered using Google.

Comment: Hmmm
I thought about this.
BUT. The problem is that i'm sending the user to the "Insert Social ID" page after the user was created. So it is after this hook that the user insert his SID...

Comment: Why not ask the user for the social id beforehand? You could spare yourself creating a new user that you'd have to delete later anyway. You can of course do it manually, too: copy the current credentials to the old user, log the user out, delete the new user, and then loginwithservice again... but that really sounds awkward and brittle.

Comment: Because it is more logical to first ask him to google/facebook connect and then show the form(the connect buttons are on the homepage)

Comment: Then just copy the data to the old user document as I wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: But then he will have to go through the other account credentials... I think I would leave it alone for now and just use the accounts meld as @masca88 said

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called **splendido:accounts-meld** that merge all the users social informations coming from the same email and also merge the user with that verified-email.

You can find more details on the github repository: https://github.com/splendido/meteor-accounts-meld

Comment: This package will only work if the 2 emails are the same.
I want to check if its multiple account by other parameter

Comment: But if you don't check by email, you will never be sure that is the same user.

Comment: As i wrote above, i make the user to enter his Social ID.